# Inline JavaScript is not enabled. Is it set in your options?

Tags: visual-studio-code, компиляция, less

Пытаюсь скомпилировать less файл в VS Code с помощью Compile Hero, но получаю ошибку:
Inline JavaScript is not enabled. Is it set in your options? in file /less/settings.less line no. 223

233: .display(flex);

Работаю с less впервые, буду благодарен помощи в решении проблемы

Answer (score 0):

Сменил Compile Hero на Easy Less, в нём в настройках можно включить поддержку inline-javascript